# Problemas ComboBox

Tags: php, formularios, combobox

Buenas tardes. Tengo un problema con un `select` para traer a lista para escoger el nombre de un trabajador de una tabla, pero ya lei guías y no encuentro cual es el detalle, ya que al probarla en web aparece solo el espacio vació anexo la parte del script

```
<li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">NOMBRE DEL ELEMENTO </label>
        <div>

        <select>
        <?php
        $mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "XXXX", "pcsdb")or 
        die("No se conecto al servidor");
        if (!$conexion){ echo (mysqli_errno());

          $consulta="SELECT id,nombre FROM personal ORDER BY id ASC";
          $resultado=mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);                                  
          ?>                                                
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
          <?php
          while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
          echo $fila['id'];
          ?>    
          <option value="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>"><?php echo$fila['nombre'];?></option>
          <?php
          }
          ?>

      </select>
        </div> 
        </li>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es como me aparece ahora al correr en el browser

Gracias de antemano

Comment: te marca un error en el log de php?

Comment: Buenas, no ni en browser visible o con el modo herramientas de desarrollador o en el php designer tampoco marca algun fallo  :/

Comment: De hecho la consulta la ejecute desde otro php y si me regresa los datos de la tabla donde estan los nombres el error no se si sea en la parte del <option>

Comment: Podria ser el espacio entre `echo` y `$fila` en esta parte `<option value="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>"><?php echo$fila['nombre'];?></option>`?

Comment: Probé ambas con y sin espacio pero no, ese fragmento de php lo reproduje en uno en blanco y devolvió datos por lo que no podría ser problemas de comunicación con la db y nomas no le hayo donde esta la falla

Comment: Bienvenido HYDE Utiliza el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/94990/edit) en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar PHP para imprimir todas las opciones de una buena vez.

```
<?php
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        echo "<option value=".$fila['id'].">".$fila['nombre']."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Ahora, creo que tu código no funciona porque estas iterando sobre tus resultados y no sobre la etiqueta `option` y creo que por eso es que sale en blanco.

Y así se veria el código completo.

```
<li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="element_2">NOMBRE DEL ELEMENTO </label>
    <div>
        <select>
        <?php
            $mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "XXXX", "pcsdb")or 
                die("No se conecto al servidor");
            if (!$conexion){ echo (mysqli_errno());
            $consulta="SELECT id,nombre FROM personal ORDER BY id ASC";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);                                  
        ?>                                                
        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        <?php
           while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
               echo "<option value=".$fila['id'].">".$fila['nombre']."</option>";
           }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div> 
</li>
```

Comment: perdon ahi si no te segui

Comment: @HYDE Edite mi respuesta para poner todo el codigo, espero que asi sea mas entendible. Tambien lo identé un poquito. :D

Comment: me creerás que aun así no respondió  :(

Comment: @HYDE Te sigue saliendo un select en blanco? No he revisado tu consulta, porque la pregunta no era de eso, pero segura que tu consulta esta bien?

Comment: @HYDE Tambien prueba quitando el primer echo del while, que quizas eso sea el problema tambien. Por cierto, para que esta ese echo alli?

Comment: se me quedo pero aun quitandolo no regresa datos el query, la consulta la probe en la consola del sql y si arroja los datos

Comment: @HYDE viste mi comentario de el primer echo? Quizas si borras/comentas esta linea `echo $fila['id'];` pueda funcionar.

Comment: Buenas si lo quite pero no sigue quedando en vacio el option

Comment: @HYDE la verdad no se que pueda estar pasando. Estoy actualmente trabajando en un proyecto y tengo exactamente el mismo codigo para uno de mis select y funciona a la perfección. Creo que necesitas investigar un poco mas, prueba inspeccionando los elementos, viendo las herramientas del desarrollador en tu navegador y cualquier otra forma que puedas verificar, porque a mi juicio todo parece bien.

Comment: @HYDE, ya he visto el problema. (creo que ya fue demasiado codigo para mi el dia de hoy) El contenido de tu option, es decir, el texto que el usuario ve, no debe ir entre corchetes (los signos de mayor y menor). Ya edite mi respuesta. Eso de seguro lo resuelve. Disculpa por el embrollo, Si te ha servido, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: no funciono  :(  ya de plano ando buscando otras opciones

Answer (score 0):

el bloque donde creas los elementos option esta condicionada al ciclo while tal ves como no pasa esta condición no te devuelve nada, trata de hacer un var_dump o un print_r de la fila para que veas si es error de la base de datos o es de tu codigo php.

```
    //Podrias hacerlo de esta manera
     <?php
       do{
         $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
         //Aki podras ver que tiene almacenado la variable fila en la primera iteración
         var_dump($fila);  // o print_r($fila);
         echo "<option value=".$fila['id'].">".$fila['nombre']."</option>";
       while($fila);
    ?>
```